# GZIP not running with crontab

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm creating a crontab to run the `scriptA.sh` everyday at midnight

```
0 0 * * * . /config/scripts/scriptA.sh 2>&1
```

The `scriptA.sh` has the following configuration:

```
 /bin/gzip /logs_backup -q *;
```

When I execute the script, outside of crontab, the script runs perfectly, compressing all the files inside of `logs_backup` folder.
However when the `scriptA.sh` is being called by crontab, it doesen't works.

I'm using the right path for gzip.

```
# which gzip
/bin/gzip
```

How I can put this script to works with crontab?

Looking for your comments and support.

Comment: Here you can find most of the reasons and solutions. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working/23438#23438

Comment: Your script only compresses files in the current directory, which in cron's case would be your home directory. If you `cd ~` first and test the script interactively again, it'll probably fail the same way.

Comment: No, the script is compressing all the files in logs_backup folder and it runs well without the crontab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
/bin/gzip /logs_backup -q *;
```

with this

```
/bin/gzip /logs_backup -q /backup/directory/*;
```

replacing with your real backup directory